# Ctrl-C not working

Tags: scripting

I am trying to make an optical encoder, so I want to cut a lot of holes at even intervals around a disk. I am trying to make a macro to apply Boolean modifiers, rotate 5 degrees, and repeat. All the tutorials I have watched say to copy the commands out of the info screen and paste it into a text editor, but when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>- <kbd>C</kbd> it doesn't seem to do anything. There's nothing in the clipboard to paste.

I have checked that my keyboard bindings are correct, and I am not sure what else to check. Do I maybe need to be in a particular mode to be able to copy out of the info screen?

Comment: Have you clicked on any text and selected it before copying?

Comment: Yes. I selected all the lines I wanted to copy, it highlighted them. I tried closing and opening blender and trying again. I tried restarting my computer as well.

Comment: Your mouse cursor must also remain hovering the info window while copying

Comment: I think it was, but I will try that and make sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the replies. It looks like the problem was my understanding of the text editor window. I just opened it as a new pane and tried to paste. It looks like I needed to "create text block" first.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing, that I can think of that would cause issues like that is if your mouse cursor is not over the editor you are trying to copy from. Blender needs to know, which part of it you are trying to copy stuff from so you need to hover the mouse over the area that your selected text is when you copy it.